# How can I make this code shorter?

Tags: perl

How can I make the following code shorter(maybe with other loops or other ideas-not with 1-Line everything), but keep the current functionality?

```
my $key = shift;
my $query = shift;
my $count = 0;

foreach my $ProteinDB (@DB) {
    my $Set = $ProteinDB->{$key};
    if($Set =~ /$query/) {
        print RWS($ProteinDB->{'ID'}) . "\n";
        $count++;
    }
}
print "$count Hits Got Found...\n";
print "\n";
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? It looks fine to me.

Comment: its fine and work perfectly, but i want to make it shorter ... its to much Code-lines ..

Comment: Are you playing code golf? If not, I wouldn't worry about how many lines of code you have. Your current code is easy to read, which is much more important.

Comment: thats True, but this mission of the Task to make Code short and useful .. but thanks for the motivation.

Comment: mission? task? is this some form of competition?

Comment: not really but our professor ask us to make an Search Engine so i make this, but its too long so i thought i am gonna ask here if someone have an idea, how i can make this shorter and still useful.

Comment: @user3075044 Who says it's too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a subroutine, I would write something like this

```
my ($key, $query) = @_;

my @wanted = grep { $_->{$key} =~ /$query/ } @DB;
print RWS($_->{ID}), "\n" for @wanted;
printf "%d Hits Got Found...\n\n", scalar @wanted;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that only takes only one line:

```
my $key = shift; my $query = shift; my $count = 0; foreach my $ProteinDB (@DB) { my $Set = $ProteinDB->{$key}; if($Set =~ /$query/) { print RWS($ProteinDB->{'ID'}) . "\n"; $count++; } } print "$count Hits Got Found...\n"; print "\n";
```

Most people prefer simple, readable code, with some exceptions to opimitize resource usage.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but if my Professor see this Code, gonna kill me :D

Comment: @user3075044, It's what you asked.

Comment: not really, i asked Shortly thats right but with other ideas, like instead of foreach with for-loop or something like that .. i don't have that experience that i can tell what i can do more with this Code .. but Thanks anyway .. i am gonna keep trying..

Comment: You asked to make it take fewer lines. ("i want to make it shorter ... its to much Code-lines .. ") Feel free to clarify if you meant something else. I even suggested in my answer what you might have meant to ask.

Comment: @user3075044 Don't worry, your professor would thank you and accept ikegami's tutelage :)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can see, is that if you're not going to use `$ProteinDB->{$key}` again, just

```
next unless $ProteinDB->{$key} =~ /$query/;
...
```

But you could also do this:

```
foreach my $ProteinDB ( grep { $_->{ $key } =~ /$query/ } @DB ) {
    print RWS($ProteinDB->{'ID'}) . "\n";
    $count++;
}
```

That way you would be narrowing down the eager list used in the foreach-loop.

Comment: If you put the result from `grep` in a list you get the count directly as the length of that list. Other than that, precisely what I would have suggested, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the motivation, but what the hey.

This is a different approach - not code golfy enough, sure, but still pretty readable.

```perl
    my ($key, $query) = @_;
    my $count = scalar
            map { print(RWS($_->{ID} . "\n")); }
            grep { $_->{$key} =~ /$query/ } @DB;
    print "$count Hits Got Found...\n";
    print "\n";
```

Not entirely equivalent, but unless you are relying in `@_` being modified by those `shift` it should work the same.

Comment: I wouldn't consider calling `print` inside `map` to be exactly readable.

Comment: That's readable in the sense it can still be easily understood. I agree that `map`s and such should be used just for transformations.